# How to mix 2 kinds of post types

Tags: custom-post-types, php, post-type

I've got a real estate website.

How can I make a connection with property and a client which is an owner of the property?
There will be a lot of properties, and sometimes 1 owner will have 2 or more properties.

I made 2 kinds of post_types - properties and owners.

Do you have any ideas?
Please help

Edit:

My adding new property is on a Frontend-page, so I have to make input with adding new taxonomie (Owner) for real estate agent. How can i do that?

Comment: Use post meta fields, save the owner's ID in a meta field for the properties.

Comment: @janh Exactly what i would do. In the Advanced Custom Fields plugin there is a relation field or something like that. Thats perfect for adding a nice UI so you dont have to search that id every time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom post type named "Property" and add a custom taxonomy named "Owner" to it.

This will help you assign properties to their respective owners even if 1 owner has multiple properties (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
I've done as you said.
Now I have another problem - My adding new property is on a Frontend-page, so I have to make input with adding new taxonomie (Owner) for real estate agent. How can i do that?

Comment: use this wp_insert_term() - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term